# Java 8 - Get the 'parent' object of a list element

Tags: java, list, collections, java-8

I have the following Code:

```
public class A {
   private String name;
   private List<B> bs;

   public A(String name) {
       this.name = name;
       this.bs = new ArrayList<>();
   }

   public void addB(B b) {
       bs.add(b);
   }
   public List<B> getBs() {
       return bs;
   }    
}

public class B {
    private String name;

    public B(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }   
}
```

And the following Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a1 = new A("A1");
        A a2 = new A("A2");

        B b1 = new B("B1");
        B b2 = new B("B2");
        B b3 = new B("B3");

        a1.addB(b1);
        a2.addB(b2);
        a1.addB(b3);

        System.out.println(a1.getBs()); // [B1, B3]

        b3.getA(); // How can I do this? => Should return A1

}
```

Now I need to get all the **B's** of an given **A**. Which works perfectly.

But I also need to get the **A** of a given **B**.

Every **B** is unique. So each **B** can only be a member of one **A**.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: "Every B is unique. So each B can only be a member of one A." <- Then you should first model your data structure that way. Because in the code you posted there is nothing that stops one from doing `a1.addB(b1); a2.addB(b1);`

Comment: Make `B` constructor package private with two arguments: `B(String name, A parent)`, and store the `A` reference in `B`. Then add a method to `A`: `public B createB(String name)` which calls this constructor as `return new B(name, this);`. This way you create `B` through `A` .If `B` cannot "live" without `A`, you can even define it as an inner class of `A`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add `A` member to `B`

```
public class B {
    private String name;
    private A a;

    public B(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public A getA() {
        return this.a;
    }
}
```

And set it when adding `B` to `A`

```
public void addB(B b) {
    bs.add(b);
    b.setA(this);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To get the `A` from a `B` you need a reference to `A` somewhere.

- each `B` can have a reference to the `A`
- you can have a collection of all the `A`s and search them to find which contains the `B`

One way to achieve what you are looking for is to set the `A` in the constructor of `B` This ensures there is exactly one `A` it is a member of

```
class A {
    private final String name;
    private final List<B> bs = new ArrayList<>();

    public A(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public B addB(String name) {
        bs.add(new B(this, name));
    }
}

class B {
    final A parent;
    final String name;

    B(A parent, String name) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public A getA() { return parent; }
```

This way a `B` can only be added to one `A` and `B` knows which one.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a1 = new A("A1");
    A a2 = new A("A2");

    B b1 = a1.addB("B1");
    B b2 = a2.addB("B2");
    B b3 = a2.addB("B3");

    System.out.println(a1.getBs()); // [B1, B3]

    assert a2 == b3.getA();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add a B to an A's List, you have to also tell the B what its A parent reference is.

```
class A {
    private List<B> children;

    public void addChild(B b) {
        if (b != null) {
            this.children.add(b);
            b.setParent(this);
        }
    }
}

class B {
    private A parent;

    public void setParent(A a) {
        if (a != null) {
            this.parent = a;
        }
    }
}
```

Watch out for circular reference and out of memory errors.  You create a B, which a reference to an A, which has a List of Bs, etc.

Comment: why is a circular reference a problem? this doesn't use much more memory, can you clarify what you mean by this warning?

Comment: This is an example.  I don't know how the OP will code the real thing.  It's just a thought about those situations where A has a B reference and B has an A.  Both have default constructors.  Could be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

As @PeterLawrey said, this is what I would do:

```
public class A {
   private String name;
   private List<B> bs;

   public A(String name) {
       this.name = name;
       this.bs = new ArrayList<>();
   }

   public void addB(B b) {
       bs.add(b, this);
   }
   public List<B> getBs() {
       return bs;
   }    
}

public class B {
    private String name;
    private A referenceToA;

    public B(String name, A referenceToA) {
        this.name = name;
        this.referenceToA = referenceToA;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public A getReferenceToA()
    {
        return referenceToA;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**b3** has no idea (and it shouldnt, because of circular references) about which collection is holding it.

you have to instead do it the opposite: find if **a1, a2 or a3 has b3**

Answer (score 0):

Use an inner class and keep the instances immutable so that you don't risk having inconsistencies:

```
class A {

    private final String name;
    private final List<B> bs;

    public A(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        bs = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public B addB(String name) {
        B b = new B(name);
        bs.add(b);
        return b;
    }

    public List<B> getBs() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(bs);
    }


    class B {

        private final String name;

        public B(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public A getA() {
            return A.this;
        }

    }

}
```